# Angular 6 Codeblock

Tags: angular5, codeblocks

app.module.ts do not import Codeblock. What steps i need follow when install it. 
https://github.com/tpadjen/ng2-prism

```
1  npm i ng2-prism --save
2 import from app.module.ts Do not see codeblock library.
3 write in component.html 
<codeblock html >
<!Doctype>
   <html>
     <body>
        <p>title</p>
     </body>
   </html>
</codeblock>
```

хочу добавить этат плугин на свой проект. Не могу. Нужна для того штобы когда я написал код внутри этого то он будет показывать тот што я написал без коплятора. если напишу `<p> Paraqraph </p>` то он будет показать `<p> Paraqraph </p>` a не

Paraqraph -

Comment: Задавайте вопросы на русском.

Comment: хочу добавить этат плугин на свой проект. Не могу. Нужна для того штобы когда я написал код внутри этого то он будет показывать тот што я написал без коплятора. если напишу 
<p> Paraqraph </p>  то он будет показать <p> Paraqraph </p> a не Paraqraph

Comment: Кнопка "править" под вопросом ..

Comment: Удалить метку Codeblock, это не имеет к нему отношения